# thread and Sleep

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, sleep, thread-sleep

I'm trying to understand how multi-threading works.

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void function1() {

   std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 1" << std::endl;
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
   std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 1 after sleeping" << std::endl;

}

void function2() {

  std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 2" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
  std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 2 after sleeping" << std::endl;

}

int main()
{

  while(true) {

     std::thread t1(function1);
     std::thread t2(function2);

     t1.join();
     t2.join();

  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

And the problem is when I run it, it stops waiting for `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));` and doesn't show the next `Hi I'm the function 1` from `std::thread t1(function1);` in the next loop, until the sleep thread ends.

1) Do you know why?

2) I want that the main continues the loop and don't wait to the t2 to finish (sleep_for() from function2 is set to 5 seconds)

Comment: "Do you know why?" Because you programmed it to do that. You start both threads, then wait until *both* finish. And then start both again. If you want one to continuously loop and *not* wait for the other, you will need to program *that* instead.

Comment: I suspect you really meant to have loops _inside_ your threads, but it's hard to know what you wanted to do when you haven't told us.

Comment: Yeah I want to sleep the thread, in other programs I want to use it, for example in games, I need to set a delay between each key press, but at same time I need to know if key is pressed GetAsyncKeyState().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your code does:

- Start thread 1

  - Outputs a message
  - Waits 1 second
  - Outputs another message
- Start thread 2

  - Outputs a message
  - Waits 5 seconds
  - Outputs another message
- Waits for both threads to finish

  - (this will take roughly 5 seconds)
- Repeats indefinitely

You have stated that this isn't what you meant to do.

I think, instead, you intended to have the "repeat" *inside* of each thread, so that they continue ticking independently and indefinitely, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void function1() {
   while (true) {
      std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 1" << std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
      std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 1 after sleeping" << std::endl;
   }
}

void function2() {
  while (true) {
     std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 2" << std::endl;
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
     std::cout << "Hi I'm the function 2 after sleeping" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::thread t1(function1);
   std::thread t2(function2);

   t1.join();
   t2.join();
}
```

Now your code does this:

- Start thread 1

  - Outputs a message
  - Waits 1 second
  - Outputs another message
  - Repeats indefinitely
- Start thread 2

  - Outputs a message
  - Waits 5 seconds
  - Outputs another message
  - Repeats indefinitely
- Waits for both threads to finish

  - (although neither ever will!)

With each thread now spinning independently, neither will ever "block" the other.

Comment: Ok thats the correct answer, so I should always use the loops inside the threads, instead in main()?

Comment: @EduardoG: Not "always" - you should do it when that's what you want your computer to do.

Comment: Can you please explain how both the thread will exit from the `while loop`?

Comment: @AbhijitPritam: It won't. I stated that in the explanation.

Comment: You always should provide a perfect answer. This program will never end and you have to kill it. Your explanation is not suffice, it is actually a poor answer. and Second join statement will never execute at all. You laugh at me that I don't have any knowledge on multi threading ask yourself now.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam: I'm done talking to you; you're bordering on abusive.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, check your comment who start it. I am not that kind of person. Still I have not down voted you.

Comment: guys it's fine thank you all, all of you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

1) This is my output and seems what I expect:

```
Hi I'm the function 1
Hi I'm the function 2
Hi I'm the function 1 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 1
Hi I'm the function 2
Hi I'm the function 1 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2
Hi I'm the function 1
Hi I'm the function 1 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2
Hi I'm the function 1
Hi I'm the function 1 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2 after sleeping
Hi I'm the function 2
Hi I'm the function 1
```

2) What you means for best performace???? `sleep_for()` works everywhere while `Sleep` is windows specific....

I suggest to use std library where you can, where put sleeps depends on your context...

Comment: No I dont want that, because the sleep_for() from function2 is set to 5 seconds, I want that the main continues the loop and don't wait to the t2 to finish.

Answer (score -2):

When you join a thread it will complete its execution and exit. Hence when you joins your thread t1.join(); and t2.join();, the second statement will execute only when first join statement completed. So in your case to crease thread continuously and execute parallel you have to detach the threads like below:-

```
int i = 0;
while(true) {

 std::thread t1(function1);
 std::thread t2(function2);

 t1.detach();
 t2.detach();

//also break your infinite loop here
if( ++i < 4)
   break;
}
```

Comment: This will create so many threads your head (and computer) will explode.

Comment: That is true. He has to control his infinite loop. Corrected my answer.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop if you stop it after the first iteration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for your advice. I have corrected by answer. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Its up to him how he want to play around with his code. Respect you feeling. Reduce it into 3. :-)

Comment: It's just a really inefficient way to achieve the same thing. Please see my answer.

Comment: You have change his whole logic.

Comment: Yes, because _that's what he asked us to do_. His code's logic did not match his intention. That's the entire point of the question.

Comment: It appears to me that you are the jealous one. It is my right to vote on any post I like, and fortunate for the OP that I am doing so.